# vim: replace all character till end of line

Tags: vim

Maybe I am being daft but can you replace all the characters from where the cursor is to the end of line by one command?  Then use <kbd>.</kbd> to do the same replace on the next line and so on.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**If** I understood your question properly, try this:

<kbd>C</kbd> (that's a capital C) will delete everything from the cursor to the end of the line and put you in *INSERT* mode, then you write your replacement, leave INSERT mode, use <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat the process somewhere else.

Comment: Fine. `:)` You're welcome.

Comment: if anyone was wondering, it is a capital C :)

Comment: Would be good to update the answer to specify that this is a capital C.

Answer (score 14):

Adding to sr_'s answer:

If your cursor starts at the same position on each line, you might be interested in the [Visual Block](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/javahelpset/jvi-vis_block.html) feature.

Type the following in order, with your cursor in the initial position:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>: *Enter visual block mode.*
- <kbd>$</kbd>: *go to the end of the line.*
- <kbd>[X]j</kbd>: *replace X with the number of lines you want to go down.*

This should create a rectangular selection going from your cursor on the first line to the end of the line [X] lines below.

You can then replace your whole selection:

- <kbd>c</kbd>: delete selction and go in insert mode.
- insert new text
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Exit insert mode; Vim will automatically repeat the step on each line selected.

I use visual block whenever I can, I thought I'd share

Comment: +1 nice answer indeed. But not really what I want since sometimes my code is not nicely formatted like that ^_~

Comment: @sardathrion; RE comment, 'nicely formatted'. Creating tables in [Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) I was able to auto fill spaces in `n+1` lines, after creating line `n` by Visual Block selecting *backwards*! In other words the shape was similar to backwards 7 or vertical flipped L, or 'not nicely formatted'. lol.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>c$</kbd> is for "change" and <kbd>R</kbd> is for "replace".

Two almost similar behavior. The former would get the line deleted before you start typing; while the latter would let you type over the characters and possibly go beyond the limit of the old line's characters displayed.

Answer (score 2):

To change every character on a line with a single character from the current column until the end of the line *while keeping the line length unchanged*:

`:.s/\%>.c./-/g` where `-` is the new character

---

`.s/./-/g` would replace every character on the current line with `-`

`\%>.c` matches from the current column

Comment: This is the only true answer. Even the visual method does not work from the middle of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Just press 'C' i.e. Capital C in the command mode, and type the replacement text.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers missed these, they don't enter insert mode.

- <kbd>D</kbd> Delete to the end of the line
- <kbd>d$</kbd>    Deletes from the cursor to the end of the line

Then of course use <kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: -1 for not entering insert mode since that is specifically what I asked for.  +1 for completeness sake.

Comment: @Sardathrion-againstSEabuse, you specifically did *not* ask for insert mode.  You simply said "replace all characters."  That is ambiguous at best.  You could want to replace with `p` for example, or replace with `<C-v>$rX`, or anything else under the sun.

Answer (score 0):

As it can be useful, once we are trying to change till the end of line.
I have created an insert mapping to perform this task, it not uses <kbd>D</kbd> because in insert mode this key is used to decreasing indentation. So it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>

```
:inoremap <C-k> <C-o>C
```